# How to allow all organisation ServiceAccounts to public to pubsub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

I know how to bind a member to be able to publish to a Pubsub topic in Google cloud normally.
Terraform example:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_member" "member" {
  project = google_pubsub_topic.example.project
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.example.name
  role = "roles/publish"
  member = "user:jane@example.com"
}
```

I'd like to understand how I could allow all serviceAccounts that belong
to my GCP organisation to automatically have publish access from their creation time.

Ideal pseudo example:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic_iam_member" "member" {
  project = google_pubsub_topic.example.project
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.example.name
  role = "roles/publish"
  member = "serviceAccounts:*.mydomain.com"
}
```

One pattern I'd considered is something like:

1. Inventory Asset Feed detects a new serviceAccount has been created
2. Asset feed publishes the resource data to pubsub
3. Pubsub triggers CloudFunction
4. CloudFunction updates a group to contain the new serviceAccount (so now you have a list of serviceAccounts not managed via Terraform)
5. Pubsub topic iam member binding allows publish role against the group updated in point 4.

Is there a simpler way of allowing all service accounts or perhaps service accounts that match a given pattern?

Comment: Your idea is interesting. The audit logs will record actions such as creating a service account. You can create an audit log export **sink** to Pub/Sub. That would replace steps #1 and #2. I do not know the time delay between an event being logged and Pub/Sub is called. Another option is to create an export sink to Cloud Storage and then trigger an event to Cloud Functions each time a new log entry is created in Cloud Storage. That would replace steps #1, #2, and #3.

Comment: Interesting. The auditlogs feed would just be an alternative to the asset feed on serviceAccount create events wouldn't it? Is there a specific reason you recommend the log sink instead of the asset feed, @JohnHanley

Comment: I do not have a preference. Since you asked for simpler ways in your question, I posted a comment with alternative strategies. I have only implemented your strategy in reverse. Removing roles from identities. I used Cloud Storage plus Cloud Functions for that one. Inventorying assets did not exist at that time.

Comment: @JakeNelson, Did the above comments resolve your issue?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar, I'm not sure if it's easier. I was hoping for a simpler pattern but there might not be one.

Comment: You can create a google workspace group, add all the users in that group. Add the group to the topic as Pub/Sub Publisher and then you can add all the service account in that group. Let me know if that is helpful.

Comment: @JakeNelson , did the above comment resolve your issue?